# Can you measure a powerbank's battery voltage at USB input connector?

Tags: batteries, usb, voltage-measurement, powerbanks

I'm currently building a portable device, that is powered by a powerbank. I want to be able to measure the current battery "percentage" of the powerbank, with an esp32.

For this i thought that i could maybe read the voltage of the battery at the *USB input connector* (The usb outputs are rectified so they are probably no use). If i can indeed read the battery voltage at the USB input connector, i could possibly convert that to a battery percentage.

However, my question is: Is it actually possible? Do the input USB lines actually reflect the battery voltage?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No. The battery terminals are not exposed anywhere on the device.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Batteries are not directly connected to USB inlets or outlets so you can't expect to measure battery voltage from any USB connector.

Even if you could measure battery voltage from USB connector, it would be extremely difficult or nearly impossible to determine battery state of charge just from the battery voltage.

If battery state of charge is needed, usually much more sophisticated chips and circuits are used to actually track the energy flowing in or out of the battery.

Battery voltage is usually only used for few simple purposes. Detecting when battery appears to be full enough to stop charging or empty enough to shut down the device. Also for detecting gross overvoltage and undervoltage to disconnect battery before it damages and may turn unstable.

Answer (score 0):

No. Standard USB provides regulated 5 V supply. If it is battery powered from a single Li-ion cell then a boost converter steps the voltage up to 5 V.

Comment: Ok so it does that on the input lines also... I thought it did that only for the usb outputs.

Comment: Standard USB Type 1 and 2 has V+, V-, D+ and D-. It doesn't have input lines and outputs.

Comment: Yes... But the powerbank has dedicated connectors for charging and separate dedicated connectors to output power. The power usb's dont even have data lines. Maybe i dind't explain myself well. By "lines" i meant the usb connectors were you plug your cables. If measuring the V+ and V- there would reflect the battery voltage

Comment: @Tom4211 The input connector expects 5 V input, which gets fed into a charger (which is part of the power bank, the "charger" that you plug into the wall is actually just a power supply), and that charger is the only thing that knows what the actual battery voltage is.

Comment: @Tom4211 The charger steps down the 5 V to the voltage required to charge the battery.

Answer (score 0):

In USB PD revision 3.1, a source or a sink can ask the other side for its battery status. It does this by sending a `00100 Get_Battery_Status` status over the current channel used for PD (which can be the D- and D+ wired for chargers implementing PD over the data wires, or the CC wire for USB C)

Once you send this PD message, the other side will respond with an Battery_Status message *if supported*. The received message will contain the battery capacity to the nearest 0.1mWh. it will also contain a status bit if the battery is charging or discharging.

If you frequently poll the power bank for the battery status, you can learn its maximum battery capacity, or if you know your consumption, you can use its reported mWh to show the time remaining